# Can I use ES Modules library from CDN?

Tags: javascript, cdn, lit-element, es6-modules

I want to use this library via CDN.
https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/lit-element

My js code is here.

```
import { LitElement, html } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lit-element@2.1.0/lit-element.js";

class MyElement extends LitElement {
    render(){
        return html`ABCD`
    }
}

customElements.define("my-element", MyElement)
```

I get following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lit-html". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Do I have to build using npm ?

---

## Update

Following code works.

```
import { LitElement, html } from "https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module"

class MyElement extends LitElement {
    render(){
        return html`ABCD`
    }
}

customElements.define("my-element", MyElement)
```

Comment: I would have thought that adding `?module` to the URL would fix it (as here https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/vbBojK?editors=1001 with unpkg.com) but I see nothing. Might be a CDN issue.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine with unpkg.com.

Answer (score 9):

Inside LitHtml and LitElement modules use bare module specifiers internally to import dependencies, and these aren't supported by JS modules yet. `LitElement` has `import { TemplateResult } from 'lit-html'`, but JS needs that `'lit-html'` replaced with whatever path to the actual file (not the abstract name of the package).

If you use the npm packages (which `cdn.jsdelivr.net` is serving up here) you have to use a build step (WebPack, Rollup, etc) to resolve all those `import` statements to either the file paths JS supports or inline all the files together.

The former is what `unpkg.com ... ?module` does, it replaces the bare reference to `lit-html` with the absolute `https://unpkg.com/lit-html@^1.1.1/lit-html.js?module`.

Comment: Alternatively download the file from CDN, replace the bare reference with the correct URL, and use this file instead of the CDN.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is great; the core issue is your CDN file(s) use a "module specifier" that is the "bare" specifier (i.e. *not* using "/" or "./" or "../") . **I fixed my issue with an `importmap`**, mapping my "bare" module specifier, to a full URL/baseURL  specifier, i.e.

```
<script type="importmap">
   { "imports": { 'bare-specificer': 'https://full-url-specifier' } } 
</script>
```

### **DETAIL ON CURRENT APPROACH: `importmap`**

I was  using jsm `three.js` modules like `ColladaLoader`, but I got this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`

This happens because I import this [`ColladaLoader.js`](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js/examples/jsm/loaders/ColladaLoader.js) file, which imports many things from `'three'` (a "bare module specifier"):

```
import {
    AmbientLight,
    // ...etc....
    sRGBEncoding
} from 'three';
//--------^ this is the "bare" module specifier problem
```

**I learned the fix from reading the [collada loader example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html) from three.js, which adds an `importmap` to its html**. I think [`importmap` is still a draft feature](https://wicg.github.io/import-maps/) but it works well to map a "bare module specifier" to a full URL /[`baseURL`](https://wicg.github.io/import-maps/#parsing)-- just what we need! (more [here](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) and [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/es-modules-in-browsers-with-import-maps/)):

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "../build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="module">
        //...
</script>
```

In my case I am using the `three.js` file located here:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r123/three.module.js

Therefore my `importmap` looks like this:

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r123/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="module">
        //...
</script>
```

I expect an `importmap` can work for you even if you have a "bare" module specifier from somewhere other than `three.js`; but the `importmap` approach  may only work in certain browsers (i.e. [caniuse suggests Edge 89+, Chrome 89+, and Opera 76+ support `type="importmap"`](https://caniuse.com/import-maps) as of 5/4/2022)

### **DETAIL ON ALTERNATIVE APPROACH: `skypack`**

**THE BELOW ANSWER DEPENDS ON `skypack` hosting *up-to-date* modules; i.e. the latest `ColladaLoader` should use `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry` which was deprecated with [the change in r125](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000359/three-geometry-is-not-a-constructor), but the latest `ColladaLoader` was *not available on skypack* AFAIK**

I'm providing this answer to suggest `skypack` as an alternative to your CDN, which works especially in the context of `three.js`, (apparently even `unpkg` might not work; read on)

The solution is discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/22008#issuecomment-863277387), which references [this migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#127--128)

> NPM: ES6 modules in examples/jsm now import using the **bare specifier**
> three. This change **breaks working with modules in cdns** such as
> https://www.jsdelivr.com/ and https://unpkg.com/. **Please use
> https://www.skypack.dev/ instead.**

So in my case I *replaced this line*:

```
import { ColladaLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js/examples/jsm/loaders/ColladaLoader.js';
```

with this line:

```
import ColladaLoader from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three-collada-loader';
```

This fixed the error re "Failed to resolve module specifier". But I did face [a different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68000359/1175496), but that's `three.js` specific; i.e. using the deprecated `Geometry` constructor, because I guess the `skypack.dev/three-collada-loader` is *not the latest code*...