# THREE.Geometry is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

Since I've been working on a three.js open world game, there I need to apply the rain effect. I followed tutorial & source code around some github repos. Don't know what I am missing?

Currently I am using **cdn** for *three.js*

[Three.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js)

[Three.module.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.module.js)

and all other flavours, but kind of seem there is something missing.

Comment: Here is a PR that solves this: https://github.com/tengbao/vanta/pull/118

Answer (score 22):

I figured it out that Three.js r125 removed support for Geometry.
We have to now use custom BufferGeometry now onwards.
https://threejs.org/manual/#en/custom-buffergeometry

Tip:
If anyone still want to use ***Geometry*** then use ***r122*** in version declaration while using *cdn*.

Comment: I meet the similar problem. I happened to replace to `THREE.TextGeometry` and meet module missing error that tells me add `"three/examples/js/geometries/TextGeometry.js"` to js file. All seem work after doing that.

Comment: Changing the three js version to 0.124.0 in the package.json works because THREE.Geometry was removed in version 125. I am using npm by the way. [link to source](https://github.com/tengbao/vanta/issues/101).