# How to import via a URL using ES modules?

Tags: javascript, esmodules

I want to import a library like `axios` directly from a URL and use it.

I don't want to add it as a `script` which adds `axios` to the `window` object (*as shown below*).

###### index.html

```
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

###### app.js

```
console.log(window.axios !== undefined); // true
const { data } = await axios.get(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"
);
console.log(data.username); // Bret
```

I want something like this wherein I can import `axios` directly from a URL.

###### index.html

```
<body>
    <script src="./app.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

###### app.js

```
import axios from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js";

console.log(window.axios !== undefined);
const { data } = await axios.get(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"
);
console.log(data.username);
```

Obviously this doesn't work because the JavaScript code delivered by the above CDN is not meant to be used with ES modules. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Skypack:

```
import axios from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/axios';

const { data } = await axios.get(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"
);
console.log(data.username);
```

Remove the jsDelivr CDN link.

Answer (score 1):

JS file provided by CDN(like yours: [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js%22)) will not provide an ES6 module export. Download and search "export default", nothing will be found.

If you use npm, you can add axios to your dependencies and use axios by
`import axios from 'axios'`

If you still want to use ES module with CDN, [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506084/can-i-use-es-modules-library-from-cdn) may help.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee If you use npm, you don't need to write script tag again. And you can use Raphael's answer with a script tag

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import axios in app.js because it has already been imported in your html, just remove the import and everything gonna work

```
    async function fetchData() {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"
      );
      console.log(data);
    }

fetchData();
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully before answering :(